# formatting datatemplate using grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Can a grid be used inside a data template to format to align the elements of the datatemplate?

I am very new to wpf and I am trying to format the presentation of a listbox by using a data template. I defined a grid within the datatemplate but it appears that the textblocks I defined was not placed in the columns I expected.

I defined a 3 column 1 row grid and planned to place each element in each respective column, but the results I got looks like this:

[image]

I was expecting to see the elements aligned properly in the columns I specified. What did I do incorrectly?

I have attached my xaml for illustration

```
    <Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
                    mc:Ignorable="d"
                    Title="MainWindow"
                    Height="350"
                    Width="525">
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name='FruitList'>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width='10*' />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width='10*' />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width='1*' />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text='{Binding FruitName}'
                                                 Grid.Column='0' />
                            <TextBlock Text='{Binding FruitColor}'
                                                 Grid.Column='1' />
                            <CheckBox IsChecked='{Binding Selected}'
                                                Grid.Column='2' />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

And my code behind:

```
namespace TestWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FruitList.ItemsSource = Fruits.getAllFruit();
        }
    }
}
```

With the binding data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestWPF.Models
{
    public class Fruit
    {
        public string FruitName { get; set; }
        public string FruitColor { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }

    }
}


namespace TestWPF.Models
{
    public class Fruits
    {
        private static List<Fruit> _fruitList;

        static Fruits()
        {
            _fruitList = new List<Fruit>();
            _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
            {
                FruitName = "Mango",
                FruitColor = "Yellow",
                Selected = false
            });
            _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
            {
                FruitName = "Mango",
                FruitColor = "Yellow",
                Selected = false
            });
            _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
            {
                FruitName = "Water Melon",
                FruitColor = "Green",
                Selected = false
            });
            _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
            {
                FruitName = "Apple",
                FruitColor = "Red",
                Selected = false
            });
            _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
            {
                FruitName = "Banana",
                FruitColor = "Yellow",
                Selected = false
            });
            _fruitList.Add(new Fruit
            {
                FruitName = "Orange",
                FruitColor = "Orange",
                Selected = false
            });
        }
        public static List<Fruit> getAllFruit(bool bSelected = false)
        {
            var result = (bSelected ?
                                        _fruitList.Where(x => x.Selected = true).ToList<Fruit>()
                                        : _fruitList.ToList<Fruit>());
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsSharedSizeScope` is set to true for outer main grid and inside data template, `SharedSizeGroup` is applied to 3 columns. You can put any name to it. Same width will be applied to those columns.

```
<Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ListBox x:Name='FruitList' HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"  />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FruitName}" Margin="5"
                                         Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FruitColor}" Margin="5"
                                         Grid.Column="1" />
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        Grid.Column="2" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Parag for the suggestion. I have 2 follow up questions: First, please note I use stackpanel, I would need to change it to grid to be able to apply your suggestion? This is not an issue, just a curious question. Second, it seems to me that I can not control the width of the column. I used '10*' but it looks like it did not affect its width. How do I make the content to expand and fill the whole grid or panel? There are still lot of space on the right. I would like to have the checkbox aligned to the far right

Comment: For checkbox, put HorizontalAlignment="Right", so that it will be moved to right.

Comment: Grid is used instead of stackpanel, because "IsSharedSizeScope" property is applicable to "Grid" only. Still if you want it, then you can wrap entire grid inside stackpanel. It will still work.

Comment: See updated answer. Mark this as helpful if it helps.

Comment: It is helpful but my main question is why columnDefinition width='10*' did not work. If I defined 1st column being 10*, second column being 10* and last column being * then both first and second columns should be of same size, it is not. But horizontal alignment sort of help.

Comment: It does work. But how will it know that how much space to acquire with respect to other rows? And regarding horizontal alignment, check that i have applied HorizontalContentAlignment to stretch. Because of this, checkbox is moved to right.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you put * or 100*, if its parent is not allowing to do so. Here in case its listbox.

Comment: could you elaborate on your comment: "It doesn't matter if you put * or 100*, if its parent is not allowing to do so. Here in case its listbox"? Are you saying listbox does not allow it? Is there a way for list box to allow it?

Comment: Dat's why I put HorizontalContentAlignment to stretch on listbox. If i remove this, then even though HorizontalAlignment is right for checkbox, it will not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140001/discussion-between-parag-and-user1205746).